# Create array from string - with complex types for highchart

Tags: jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have this text string:

```
 [[Date.UTC(2012,8, 1), 2],[Date.UTC(2012,9, 31), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,0, 31), 3]]
```

and when I paste it like that, it works fine, but getting it from a string does not work, Can't seem to use JSON.parse() because of the Date.UTC thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/NmFjj/

two samples shown. I need to be able to convert that string to an array so the highcharts works correctly.

Comment: if you have no control over the `Date.UTC` being inserted, chances are you're going to have to *:gulp:* `eval()` it first.

Comment: Eval does work, was hoping there would be a better way. I do control the creation of the text string, and I create the Date.UTC() but it is based on the docs from Highcharts, as that is how they expect dates (at least in the example I saw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try eval instead of JSON.parse.